# ReportingServices SetReportDataSources Exception operation you are attempting on item error

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm just trying to set a shared data source.
I keep getting the exception

> The operation you are attempting on item is not allowed for this item type.

Maybe I have something mixed around but I'm unable to nail it down.

filepath=/Base/Vendor (full path of the report);
datasource = IBBase

```
 public static void UpdateDataSource(string filepath, string datasource)
    {
        ReportingService rs = new ReportingService();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        ServicesReport.DataSourceReference reference = new ServicesReport.DataSourceReference();
        reference.Reference = filepath;
        ServicesReport.DataSource[] dataSources = new ServicesReport.DataSource[1];
        ServicesReport.DataSource ds = new ServicesReport.DataSource();
        ds.Item = (ServicesReport.DataSourceDefinitionOrReference)reference;
        ds.Name = datasource;
        dataSources[0] = ds;

        try
        {
            rs.SetReportDataSources(filepath, dataSources);
            Console.WriteLine("New reference set for the report.");

        }

        catch (SoapException e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This Connect call reports the same error code using the SetItemDataSources method: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/318868/ssrs-2005-sp2-setitemdatasource-web-method-bug#details.

The bottom-line of the answer given by Microsoft is that the data source name cannot be arbitrary. It has to match the existing one associated with the current report. Can you check that your report configuration on the Report Server refers to the EXACT same data source as you're trying to connect to in your code?

If not, you have found a probable cause to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This was very helpful.  Here is what worked for Me...

```
//************ Associate the shared datasource to the report ************

//Step 1 - Get the datasource for the report
DataSource[] _currReportDataSource = 
_ssrsService.GetItemDataSources(report.Path);

//Step 2 - Create a reference to the shared datasource for the tenent
SSRS_Service.DataSourceReference _dsRef = new DataSourceReference();
_dsRef.Reference = <Path to the datasource>     //Usually like "/Folder Name/Datasource Name"

//Step 3 - Create a new datasource object with reference to the shared     datasource for the tenent
DataSource _newReportDataSource = new DataSource();
_newReportDataSource.Item = _dsRef;     //this line sets the reference of the object to the shared datasource
_newReportDataSource.Name = _currReportDataSource[0].Name;      //we will use the current name of the report as it is exists now.  Defaultly named as "DataSource1"

//Step 4 - Load the datasource object (with reference to shared datasource) to a temp array as the SetItemDataSources method requires an array.
DataSource[] dsArray = new DataSource[1];
dsArray[0] = _newReportDataSource;

_ssrsService.SetItemDataSources(report.Path, dsArray);      //Set the datasource for the report to the shared datasource
```